# is there any ROS package for exploration in Groovy (ubuntu 12.10)?

Tags: ros, exploration, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have been searching for a ROS package for exploration in ubuntu 12.10 and I have not found one yet - see my related [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/57084/installation-of-explore-package-in-groovy-ubuntu-1210/)

So, does anyone know about one which is compatible with ROS-groovy ? Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57090/is-there-any-ros-package-for-exploration-in-groovy-(ubuntu-12.10)?/) by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 483 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Already posted this answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/55882/exploration-tutorial-for-gazeboerratic-or-p3dx/), but it fits your question very well, so here goes:

You can try out the [hector_exploration_planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_exploration_planner) package that we use with great success for exploration while participating in the RoboCup Rescue Robot League. There currently isn't an example available interacting with the navigation stack, but implementing a node that calls the service provided by the [hector_exploration_node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_exploration_node) and feeds the provided goals to move_base should be straightforward.

[Real world example](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=486860097994941&set=a.477301558950795.127503.415076305173321&type=1&theater) (RoboCup Rescue 2012 final, note that the background checkerboard is on a 1m grid)

Two examples of exploration in (gazebo) simulation:
[image: Maze]

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2013-03-05**:
I had already seen it but I thought that it was not ported to groovy because you can find many ros-groovy-hector packpages via apt-get but not the navigation - I had to install it via source code. Will try it, thank you!

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-03-07**:
We haven't done extensive documentation of the package yet and it might still change a little bit. For those reasons it's not yet available as a .deb package. But generally, exploration works well so far for us.

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2013-03-07**:
Is there any online reference available?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-10-17**:
Looks interesting. Do you plan to catkinize hector navigation in the near future? And is the maze world file publicly available?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-10-18**:
I have forked the repo and catkinized a couple of packages to make easier for us to give it a try. Tell me if you want me to catkinize the rest when I have a bit extra time.

**Comment by [Ashwin27](https://answers.ros.org/users/19896/ashwin27/) on 2014-08-01**:
@jorge, any chance you could share the link to the catkinized repo you mentioned? I've been trying to catkinize the hector_exploration planner myself.